# Access Runnable's method before it runs

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a `Runnable` to an `AsyncTask` and then set the results of `doInBackgroud` to it and run it.

I am trying the following code with no success.

```
// MyActivity.java
public void click(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button) {
        new AsyncHTTP(myAsyncClassCallback()).execute();
    }
}

public Runnable myAsyncClassCallback() {
    return new StringRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,result.toString());
        }
    };
}
```

```
// StringRunnable.java
public class StringRunnable implements Runnable {
    volatile String result;

    public void setResult(String res) {
        this.result = res;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

```
// MyAsyncClass.java
public class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    private Runnable myCallback;

    public MyAsyncClass(Runnable runnable){
        this.myCallback = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(){
        // works normally
        return someString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myCallback.setResult(result); // <--- This is my question
        myCallback.run();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

So I get the message:

> Cannot resolve method setResult

How can I fix this? Is this some access issue?

Comment: As a side note, it will be better to use the asynTask and get rid of Runnable class. You can do your Runnable's task of `do something with result` inside asyncTask's onPostExecute. The code using both is not only irrelevant but also can lead to two different background threads with no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `myCallback` a `Runnable`, but `Runnable` does not contain a definition for `setResult(String result)`. Your extended class, however, does. Which means you should cast the `Runnable` to a `StringRunnable`, which it actually is

```
((StringRunnable)myCallback).setResult(result);
```

Or you should declare your `myCallback` as a `StringRunnable`

```
private StringRunnable myCallback;
```

EDIT: as Unihedron pointed out, the last options means you have to change your Constructor as well

```
private StringRunnable myCallback;

public MyAsyncClass(StringRunnable runnable){
    this.myCallback = runnable;
}
```

I should note, however, that it is, in your case, unnecessary to use two non-UI-threads. `AsyncTask` is a `Thread` as well

Comment: Note that second method would require a change in the constructor, which currently is `this.myCallback = runnable;` where `Runnable runnable` is declared.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
private Runnable myCallback;
```

use

```
private StringRunnable myCallback;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cast `Runnable` to `StringRunnable` like this:

```
((StringRunnable)myCallback).setResult(result);
```